# Node.js execute python script through shell script with passed arguments

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, shell

So I have some javascript code that will execute a shell scipt:

```
    var exec = Meteor.npmRequire('child_process').exec;
    exec("/Users/ray/Desktop/scripts/hello.sh");
```

This shell scipt will execute a python file. I was wondering how could I pass this shell script some arguments for the python script from my javascript code?

Comment: `exec("python /home/user/script.py foo bar");`

Comment: @taesu will this [work for node.js 0.12.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773478/windows-android-app-how-to-can-client-side-node-js-0-12-x-4-x-execute-python)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you were to add your arguments as such:

`exec("/Users/ray/Desktop/scripts/hello.sh arg1 arg2 arg3");`

It should work.